# What is the style of font called that is typically used in newspaper mastheads?

Tags: font-identification, style-identification, font-face, blackletter

Does anyone know of a font suitable for the title of a newspaper? It is also the type that's used for the first letter of a chapter of a book (and is so calligraphic, you can't tell if it has serifs or not).

I am looking for something like the one used by the "newspaper clipping generator" at [fodey.com](http://www.fodey.com/generators/newspaper/snippet.asp):

[image: Newspaper Title]
<sup>Generated at [fodey.com](http://www.fodey.com/generators/newspaper/snippet.asp)</sup>

Answer (score 23, accepted):

That style of lettering is called [**Blackletter**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackletter) (also sometimes loosely called "gothic script", or "old English"), and if you do a search for "blackletter font" you'll find [plenty of fonts](http://www.myfonts.com/search/blackletter/fonts/) that imitate this style.

You're probably looking for something specifically like [Old English by Linotype](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/old-english/old-english/) or [Monotype Old English](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/old-english-text/std/) which have been relatively popular for this purpose.

Monotype old English image from identifont:

[image: Old English]

Or if you're looking for free fonts, [UniFraktur](http://unifraktur.sourceforge.net/) is a free blackletter one which appears authentic but has a different style of capitals to what you're after.  [Meyne Textur](http://www.dafont.com/meyne-textur.font) is somewhat along the theme you're looking for.  There are probably others, of varying quality.

Meyne Textur free font:

[image: Meyne Textur]

Comment: Interestingly, blackletter writing fell out of favour hundreds of years ago pretty much everywhere except in Germany, where a form of it (Fraktur) was still highly popular well into the 20th century.  Eventually the Nazi party phased it out.  A [sample from 1938](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/40/Fraktur_humboldtfraktur.png) shows what we outside Germany may consider to be a centuries-old form of writing, but in Germany was in common (not even "trying to look old") use less than 100 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

There is a whole bunch of them over at [DaFont](http://www.dafont.com/theme.php?cat=401) and they are mostly free. The typeface style is called Gothic (of the medieval variety ;)).

Comment: The term "Gothic" has also been used as another word for ["sans-serif"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif#Other_names_for_sans-serif) - which could lead to confusion.  "Gothic script" or "blackletter" would be less ambiguous.

Comment: You are absolutely right